# c++ ocurrence of a std::string inside another std::string

Tags: c++, stdstring

i am tryng to count the ocurrence of a std::string inside another std::string using this:

```
   static int cantidadSimbolos(const std::string & aLinea/*=aDefaultConstString*/,
                                  const std::string & aSimbolo/*=aDefaultSimbolSeparador*/)
        {
            if(aSimbolo.empty()) return 0;
            if (aLinea.empty()) return  0;
            int aResultado=0;
//This is the line that the compiler doesnt like
           aResultado=std::count(aLinea.begin(),aLinea.end(),aSimbolo);
            return aResultado;
        }
```

but the compiler doesnt like it, this is the error that the compiler emits:

> error: no match for ‘operator==’ in
>   ‘_*first.*_gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
>   _Container>::operator* >() == __value’

any help??
thx in advance!

Comment: I still don't understand why people are not using English variable and function names. I probably never will.

Comment: If you're trying to find `aaa` inside `aaaaaa` how many times do you want it to be?

Comment: Whats wrong with [string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)?

Comment: Example [using find](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#C.2B.2B)

Comment: Also, as always, `clang` gives a more meaningful error message: `invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'const std::basic_string<char>')`. It seems that the problem is that `std::count()` dereferences the iterator while stepping through the range, and tries to compare **that** dereferenced value with its 3rd argument. And apparently `std::string` doesn't implement `operator==(std::string, char)`.

Comment: Thx peter ( Peter Wood )!, i will use link. i hope someone can respond my question.

Comment: `std::string` is a container of `char`'s. `std::count` is an algorithm that compares all elements in a container, with a single element. You get an error because the elements of your container(`char`) are not comparable to the single element you pass (`std::string`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will find the count of the non-overlapping occurrences of a given string.

```
using namespace std;

static int countOccurences(const string & line, const string & symbol) {

if (symbol.empty()) return 0;
if (line.empty()) return 0;
int resultCount = 0;

for (size_t offset = line.find(symbol); offset != string::npos;
     offset = line.find(symbol, offset + symbol.length()))
{
    resultCount++;
}

 return resultCount;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << countOccurences("aaabbb","b") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The find function will return either an iterator to the first element of the value it matches to or return 'last' hence string::npos. This ensures no overlap with offset + symbol.length().

I did my best to translate the variables to English for readability for English users.